# Allowing Data to persist across all Swift3 Files

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

Really simple question here. I have some data that I am loading from a database when my iOS app is launched. I want this data to persist across all viewControllers, so that I can access it as required. I currently have a Object "Books" that this data is loaded into. I am able to load the data into an array, but unable to access it throughout the entire project.

This is data that will be updated and changed throughout the project at the users request.

Any ideas on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way is a singleton class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a singleton, for example:

```
class BookHelper
{
    static let shared = BookHelper()

    var books = [Book]()

    func getBooks() -> [Book] {
        return books
    }

    func loadBooks() {
        // you could load your books here
    }
}
```

When you need to access your books:

```
let books = BookHelper.shared.getBooks()
```